# Exercise help: Asteroid impacts on the Earth modelled with a Poisson distribution

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, poisson-distribution

Suppose that asteroid impacts on the earth are modelled with a Poisson distribution. Suppose large asteroids are estimated to impact the Earth once every 50000 years.  Poisson distribution predicts the probability of $k$ events when the event frequency is $\lambda$ to be $\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda}$

How many years are required for the probability of at least one1km diameter impact to exceed 10%?

How would I solve this question?

Answer (score 1):

You have a mean of 1 impact every 500 000 years.

1. Let's study the number of impacts $X$ in the next 500 000 years: $X\sim\text{Pois}(\lambda)$ with $\lambda = 1$. $$P(X>1) = 1-P(X=1)-P(X=0)$$ Now replace $P(X=k)$ with the expression given by the poisson distribution.
2. Let's study the number of impacts $X$ in the next 100 000 years: $X\sim\text{Pois}(\lambda)$ with $\lambda = \frac{1}{5}$. 
   Give $P(X=0)$
3. Let's study the number of impact $X$ in the next $y$ years: $X\sim\text{Pois}(\lambda)$ with $\lambda = \frac{y}{500000}$.
   $$P(X>0)>0.5$$
   $$P(X=0) < 0.5$$
   $$e^{-\lambda} < 0.5$$
   Express with $y$